# TextPad Questions!

Tags: ide, textpad

Someone must know this but can anyone help me with the following please

1. When I open a folder I want the default format to be 'Details' and not list!!!! (ie sorted by time modified desc)
2. When I have a doc open I want to be able to see the folder that the doc is contained inside of in the explorer window within TextPad. I use the explorer window but I cannot find a way to get the explorer to navigate to the folder that the document is inside of!!
3. XML formatting - I ve tried addin and they were useless - All I want is decent XML syntax like VS2005 + formatting capability... Why is this not present!!

Other then that love it love it love it

Comment: for #3, there are several XML syntax coloring add-ons on the Helios Software site - one of them should be fine for you; if not: why don't you create your own! It's really not that hard....

Comment: Hi, you don't necessarily need to copypaste tabbed text or to wrap text in code block. Please remove tabs and it'll be better readable :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to use TextPad all the time. It's a very good text editor, but it's lacking some of the features that you want.

I personally think you'll like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) a lot better. **It's free** and open source. Also if you download the plugin for XML Support you will get lots of features for [XML editing](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) like:

- XML syntax Check
- XML Schema (XSD) + DTD Validation
- XML tag autoclose
- Pretty print
- Linearize XML
- Current XML Path
- Conversion XML <-> Text
- Comment / Uncomment
- XPath expression evaluation

Comment: @ChloeRadshaw: TextPad and Notepad++ are to different programs. Certain programs will have features over others, thats what makes people choose one of the other. I chose Notepad++ because I like this feature and the fact that it was **free**.

Comment: I still like textpad the best...although it sucks how slow the development of new features or improvement of old ones is.

Comment: IMO, TextPad shot themselves in the foot right out of the gate by not using standard shortcut keys.  Sure, you can change the "template" for the shortcut keys - but the number of developers that uninstall it off their machines at my company based on Ctrl-F not bringing up the Find dialog alone is incredible.

Comment: Yes, Ctrl-F can be used in Textpad to trigger "Find". Go to Preferences and select Editor > Keystroke compatibility and set to "Microsoft Applications"